# Font viewer which can preview sample text?

Tags: linux, open-source, debian, font-utility, font

I'm looking for something quite particular, which I am unsure exists.

I want a font installer/uninstaller and previewer that I can use to tag and sort fonts, so that they're easier to find when I need them. I also want to be able to type in sample text in a field, and then see that same text written in the different fonts that are presented. Additionally, I want to be able to "see" what all the fonts in front of me look like, instead of having to individually click on every single one, as with the "Font Management" setting in KDE Plasma, which is a pain.

Most of the bigger font download websites have this feature for viewing all fonts at once and typing in sample text. Examples: https://www.1001fonts.com/, https://www.1001freefonts.com/index.php, https://www.fontspace.com/, https://fontsgeek.com/, *et cetera*.

So, to recap, I'd like the following:

- Font tagging and organising into categories;
- Preview all fonts at once without having to click on each one separately;
- Type in sample text to see what the result will look like.

IMPORTANT: I'm using Linux, and mostly prefer FOSS. I really don't mind building anything from source if it's not available as a binary, but it would be cool to just have a .DEB package or AppImage. I guess that'd simply be a nice bonus. By the way, I'm not the biggest fan of Snap and Flatpak, but hey, if it's all there is…

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **Fonty Python** can be suitable: https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fontypython

Then there is **FontBase** (https://fontba.se/) which is a nice piece of software, but is not free for all features (like tagging.)